# Tell WYGWAM not to wrap certain text in a <p> tag

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, mx-jumper

I've built in a shortcode-like method using mx_jumper that works well, for the most part. I have Matrix field called `blog_images` where the user can upload up to 10 images for a post. Then they include the images in the post's WYGWAM field wherever they want by placing a shortcode referencing the image's ID in the Matrix field, like so:

`{image_2}`

In the template for a blog post I cycle through all images in that Matrix field like this:

```
{blog_images}
    {exp:mx_jumper:put name="image_{row_count}"}
        <figure class="{placement} {size} {css_classes}">
            {image_standard}
                <img src="{url}" alt="{alt_text}" width="{width}" height="{height}">
                {exp:stash:set name="image_width" parse_tags="yes"}{width}{/exp:stash:set}
            {/image_standard}
            {if caption}
                <figcaption style="width: {exp:stash:get name='image_width'}px;"{if "{caption-placement}" == "sidebar"} class="sidebar"{/if}>
                    {caption}
                </figcaption>
            {/if}
        </figure>
    {/exp:mx_jumper:put}
{/blog_images}
```

Then I do the replacing in the content like so:

```
{exp:mx_jumper:out_global}
    {blog_post_content}
{/exp:mx_jumper:out_global}
```

This works really well with one exception:

For formatting purposes I need to have the shortcode on it's own line in WYGWAM. Problem is WYGWAM wants to wrap it in a `<p>` tag, like this:

```
<p>
<figure>…</figure>
</p>
```

… which is improper markup. The browsers try to be helpful and "correct" it by making it this:

```
<p></p>
<figure>…</figure>
<p></p>
```

… leaving space before and after the `<figure>` tags. Yuck!

Can I tell WYGWAM *not* to wrap text that starts and ends with `{}` in a paragraph tag? If not, other suggestions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I tell WYGWAM not to wrap text that starts and ends with {} in a paragraph tag? If not, other suggestions??

For WYGWAM, I don't think you can do that specifically, but you might be able to modify how it responds to paragraph tags by adjusting the Advanced Settings for your configuration.

[image: WYGWAM Advanced Settings]

If that doesn't work, you could try [Streeng](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/streeng) to kill the empty `<p></p>` pair via find and replace:

```
{exp:streeng find="<p></p>" replace=""}
 {blog_images}
   ...
 {/blog_images}
{/exp:streeng}
```

UPDATE:

```
{exp:streeng find="<p><figure>" replace="<figure>" trim="both"}
 {blog_images}
   ...
 {/blog_images}
{/exp:streeng}
```

OR you can try get really hack-a-licious:

```
{exp:streeng trim="both"}
{exp:replace_plus}
  {replace_area find="<p><figure>" replace="<figure>"}
  {replace_area find="</figure></p>" replace="</figure>"}
    {blog_images}
      ...
    {/blog_images}
  {/replace_area}
  {/replace_area}
 {/exp:replace_plus}
 {/exp:streeng}
```

Comment: Hiya Stephen. Thanks! Do you know if streeng minds that the `<p>` tags have whitespace inside?

Comment: Also, the `<p>` tag won't be empty in the markup — it will be wrapped around a `<figure>` tag. It's the browser that tries to *fix* the faulty markup by closing the `<p>` tag. So streeng won't even find an empty `<p>` tag.

Comment: Ah, if it's the browser, then there's nothing you can do in EE. You'll need some js to fix it.

Comment: Or... change the streeng settings. See my edit above.

Comment: What I need to do is make sure that `<figure>` tags are *not* wrapped in `<p>` tags in WYGWAM, or at least not output that way in the template. Playing with this right now: `{exp:streeng find="<p><figure" replace="<figure"}`

Comment: Re: your streeng edit. What about the closing `</p>` tag?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure of how to prevent WYGWAM from creating the `<p>` tag around `<figure>`. Not saying there's not a way, but, if there is, I don't know it.